# Mounting Samba share to Docker container

Tags: docker, samba, mount, file-permissions

#### Goal

On my server I am runing various Docker containers, specifically a syncthing container. In addition I am also using my server for different Samba shares.

My goal is to mount the host directory `/mnt/basis/software/backups/syncthing` to the syncthing container, so that all files that are synchronized are accessible under the Samba share "backups". Please note that the the parent directory `backups` is used for a Samba share. The `syncthing` directory has the following permissions and labels set:

```
drwxrwx---. 4 myuser applications system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0     11 12. Jan 00:06 syncthing
```

#### Configuration

The config of my Samba share "backups" looks as following:

```
[backups]
path = /mnt/basis/software/backups
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
read only = no
valid users = @applications
public = no
guest ok = no
force group = applications
directory mask = 0770
force directory mode = 0770
create mask = 0770
force create mode = 0770
inherit acls = yes
```

The docker-compose file used for syncthing is the following:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  syncthing:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/syncthing:1.27.2
    container_name: syncthing
    hostname: syncthing-docker
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1006
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
      - /mnt/basis/software/docker/syncthing:/config:z
    ports:
      - 8384:8384
      - 22000:22000/tcp
      - 22000:22000/udp
      - 21027:21027/udp
    restart: always
```

Within the docker-compose file, I am specifying the suffix `:z` for the mount volume in order to ensure a correct labeling of the directory. Furthermore I ensure that the correct user ID and group ID are assigned. In my case this is the group ID `1006` which refers to the group `applications` (as mentioned in my Samba share config).

#### Problem

At the moment, the current setup is not working properly. I can successfully start the syncthing container and the web application can be accessed at port 8384. I was also able to confirm during a small test that files are synchronised successfully. However, it is no longer possible to access the directory `/syncthing` within the Samba share, as the relabeling using the `:z` suffix removes the `samba_share_t` label from the directory and adds the `container_file_t` label, making the directory inaccessible. It seems that the problem is the relabeling of the mounted directory.

But if I omit the suffix `:z` and the directory is not relabled, the container is not started correctly. I have looked at the container logs and found that apparently the permission is denied as shown below.

```
[start] 2024/01/12 01:24:04 INFO: syncthing v1.27.2 "Gold Grasshopper" (go1.20.11 linux-amd64) root@buildkitsandbox 2024-01-02 08:15:35 UTC [noupgrade]
[start] 2024/01/12 01:24:04 INFO: Generating ECDSA key and certificate for syncthing...
[start] 2024/01/12 01:24:04 WARNING: Failed to load/generate certificate: save cert: open /config/cert.pem: permission denied
```

It seems that I did something wrong when setting the permissions for the `syncthing` directory.

#### Question

Based on the previous explanations, I would like to kindly ask if it is possible to mount the directory `/mnt/basis/software/backups/syncthing` into the syncthing container, so that I can access the synchronized files from a remote machine via the Samba share?

I would be very grateful for any kind of idea or advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turnes out, that the problem in fact originates from SELinux policies. Specifically, the podman container process (labeled as `container_t`) could not access the samba share directory (labeled as `samba_share_t`).

After some research, I found this post:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728801/host-wide-consequences-of-setting-selinux-z-z-option-on-container-bind-mounts

As described there, we can use `ausearch` to inspect SELinux denial decisions and create an exception rule for a denial with `audit2allow`. However, after some back and forth testing, I came up with this SELinux module specification:

```
module docker-samba 1.0;

require {
    type container_t;
    type samba_share_t;
    type mnt_t;
    class dir { read write setattr getattr create rename open add_name rmdir remove_name lock watch};
    class file { read write setattr getattr create rename open lock unlink append};
}

#============= container_t ==============
allow container_t samba_share_t:dir { read write setattr getattr create rename open add_name rmdir remove_name lock watch};
allow container_t samba_share_t:file { read write setattr getattr create rename open lock unlink append};
allow container_t mnt_t:dir { setattr };
```

It is based on the official SELinux specification [PolicyStatements](https://selinuxproject.org/page/PolicyStatements) and [ObjectClassesPerms](https://selinuxproject.org/page/ObjectClassesPerms)

The module can then be installed as following:

```
sudo checkmodule -M -m -o docker-samba.mod docker-samba.te
sudo semodule_package -m docker-samba.mod -o docker-samba.pp
sudo semodule -i docker-samba.pp
```

To check if your module specification was indeed correct, you can again inspect the SELinux denial messages using `ausearch` as described before.

Comment: Thanks you very much for sharing! I was trying to give the PaperlessNGX container access to one of my shares and this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you using a Linux based docker container, then Z: is not recognized because that's windows/Microsoft

So in your volumes you need to specify a linux path for example /data

```
volumes:
 -  /mnt/basis/software/docker/syncthing:/var/syncthing
```

Also make sure the 1006 has enough permissions to the files/directory/share

There is an example docker-compose on their github
https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/blob/main/README-Docker.md

```
    ---
version: "3"
services:
  syncthing:
    image: syncthing/syncthing
    container_name: syncthing
    hostname: my-syncthing
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    volumes:
      - /wherever/st-sync:/var/syncthing
    ports:
      - 8384:8384 # Web UI
      - 22000:22000/tcp # TCP file transfers
      - 22000:22000/udp # QUIC file transfers
      - 21027:21027/udp # Receive local discovery broadcasts
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `z` suffix is not for refering to a Windows directory, but is used to label shared or unshared volumes, as posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651198/podman-volume-mounts-when-to-use-the-z-or-z-suffix). I have double-checked that the group 1006 has the proper permissions.

Comment: That's about podman and this is docker compose. I don't think you can refer to shared volume in docker compose